# NameError: name 'OutOfBoundsDatetime' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, nameerror

I want to convert a columns of my DataFrame (df) to a datetime type. So I use the function `pd.datetime` like this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

But my df have some date in form '0001-01-01', so I have an error telling me:

```
OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-01-01 00:00:00
```

So, the issue is when I try to extract all rows on my df which has a 'OutOfBoundsDatetime' error when I call the `pd.to_datetime()` function.

My code

```
good_id = []
notGoog_id = []  
for i in range(len(my_df)):
    try:
       pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'][i])
       good_id.append(i)
    except OutOfBoundsDatetime:
       notGood_id.append(i)
```

But when I do this, I have an error telling me:

```
NameError: name 'OutOfBoundsDatetime' is not defined
```

Someone know why this Python doesn't recognize this error?

Comment: I'm on Python 3.9

Comment: This error is not from standard Python, but from pandas: `pandas.errors.OutOfBoundsDatetime`. See also from the [docs](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-timestamp-limits) why this happens and a link therein how to represent values outside the acceptable range.

Comment: ah so `pd` stands for `pandas`. I wasn't familiar with the package

Comment: Thanks @Reti43! ```pandas.errors.OutOfBoundsDatetime``` works! Exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the exception, you could sanitize your input upfront. Like checking the date if it's within a certain bound before trying to parse it.

```
import re


dates = ["0001-01-01", "2021-03-01"]
regex = "(\\d{4})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})"

for date in dates:
    p = re.compile(regex)
    m = p.match(date)
    if int(m.group(1)) > 1970:
        print(f"{date} good")
    else:
        print(f"{date} bad")
```

Comment: Thanks! it's could resolve my issue, but i need  to run some task in production and just extract some rows if this error comes out. I just need to run my program and if the date is bad, so i tell to the prod the problem why the program doesn't work on this row and let the program continue. So i really need this error comes out and not do a special function just for that.